# Web Application Architecture Diagrams

Tags: diagram

I am working on a Social networking site. I have to create High level design document. In this document there is one section "Application Architecture diagram". I haven't worked on architecture diagram. I know what will be the architecture of our application as it is explained by my Senior. but I don't understand the concept of "Application Architecture diagram".

What should be included in this diagram? Where to place which components? Can anybody help me to understand how to create **application architecture diagram**

Comment: Do you perhaps mean an class-diagramm or an package diagramm from uml?

Comment: nop i have to create web application architecture diagram, component diagram, deployment diagram and system diagram.

Answer (score 0):

according the application you developed, specify the technology you will use for developments with your project functional flow. They will be represented as diagrammatically. It will contain (i) Functional Flow, (ii) Process Flow, (iii) Unit test cases. Otherwise ask your senior regarding this.